# Making My Own Button Class

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I am using the TornadoFX framework and Kotlin to create a simple desktop app that lets a user click a button, select a USFM file, and spits the contents of that USFM file into a text area. I've got the basics working, but I want to step my code up by separating out the logic for my button. Currently, my one and only view defines the logic for what action to take when my button is clicked. The code looks like this:

```
import tornadofx.*
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
import javafx.stage.FileChooser
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import javafx.scene.control.Label
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea
import java.io.File

class AppView : View() {
    override val root: BorderPane by fxml()

    val chooseFile: Button by fxid<Button>()
    val fileName: Label by fxid<Label>()
    val textArea: TextArea by fxid<TextArea>()
    lateinit var fileChosen: File
    init {
        title = "USFM Viewer"
        root.lookup(".button").setOnMouseClicked {
            var fileFilter = arrayOf(FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("USFM files", "*.usfm"))
            fileChosen = chooseFile("Select a USFM File", fileFilter, FileChooserMode.Single)[0]
            fileName.text = fileChosen.name
            val fileParser = USFMFileParser(fileChosen)
            val printout = fileParser.readFile(fileChosen)
            textArea.text = printout.joinToString()
        }

    }
}
```

My initial plan is to create my own button class that that inherits from the Button class and either overrides or initializes with its own method for handling click events. The goal would be to simply declare the button in my view file and not have to define extra logic for it. I seem to be struggling in getting this work.

This is my prototype for my custom button class:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import javafx.stage.FileChooser
import tornadofx.*
import java.io.File

class ChooseFileButton: Button(){
    val fileFilter = arrayOf(FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("USFM File", "*.usfm"))
    val files: List<File>
        get() = chooseFile("Select a USFM File", fileFilter, FileChooserMode.Single)
    init {
        action { println(this.files[0].name) }
    }
}
```

Also, here is my FXML file to provide more context on the elements in my stage:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<BorderPane id="appview"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            prefHeight="635"
            prefWidth="500">
    <top>
        <FlowPane>
            <Button fx:id="chooseFile" id="chooseFile" text="Choose File..." />
            <Label fx:id="fileName" id="fileName" text="No File Chosen"/>
        </FlowPane>
    </top>
    <center>
        <ScrollPane>
            <TextArea fx:id="textArea" id="textArea"></TextArea>
        </ScrollPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Does anyone have any tips, advice, links, etc. for how I can separate the button logic from the view? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create a Button subclass for this. Just create an extension function on `ButtonBase` that configures the button the way you want, and call that function once for each button. You should also consider kicking out FXML for using the type safe builders, which would make this even more convenient, not to mention type safe.

Here is an example of such a function which lets you specify a parser, filters and load the file into a target string property. There is also a default parser which just loads the file as is.

```
fun ButtonBase.loadFile(target: Property<String>,
                        parser: (File) -> String = { Files.readAllBytes(it.toPath()).toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) },
                        filters: Array<FileChooser.ExtensionFilter>) {
    action {
        chooseFile(text, filters, FileChooserMode.Single).firstOrNull()?.let {
            target.value = parser.invoke(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a complete type safe builder example using the function:

```
class FileChooserTest : View() {
    val fileContent = SimpleStringProperty()

    override val root = borderpane {
        center {
            textarea(fileContent)
        }
        bottom {
            buttonbar {
                button("Select a USFM File") {
                    loadFile(fileContent, filters = arrayOf(FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("USFM File", "*.usfm")))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to stick to FXML (maybe you like to just type stuff :), you would call it like this:

```
class AppView : View("USFM Viewer") {
    override val root: BorderPane by fxml()

    val chooseFile: Button by fxid<Button>()
    val textArea: TextArea by fxid<TextArea>()

    init {
        chooseFile.loadFile(textArea.textProperty(), filters = arrayOf(FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("USFM File", "*.usfm")))
    }
}
```

The `loadFile` function can be expanded any way you like, for example by returning the selected file, assigning a separate title to the file chooser dialog etc.

Another tip: In your example code you located the button using the `by fxml()` delegate, but then you did another `lookup` to locate the button again. You should reuse the button you already located.

Comment: thank you so much man. This was super helpful. I did a little modifying to the view to get it the way I like it, and setting the text in the text area to the contents of the file. Thanks again

Comment: Happy to help :))